# How can I print values in C without specifying their types, like done with "cerr << (A) << endl" in C++?

Tags: c++, c

In C++, having

```
#define DEBUG(A) cerr << (A) << endl;
```

I can send anything to it, and it can print it. However, in C, I must specify its type with %d, %c or %s etc. But I don't want to write its type all time, I want to use `fprintf` like `cerr`. How can I do that?

For example: in C

```
#define DEBUG(A) X // X is what I want to write 
...
// in function, when I put
DEBUG(5);          // I just want to print 5 
// or, with same statement, when I say 
DEBUG('a');        // output : a
```

Comment: are you sure you want to use `endl` ? It provokes a flush of the stream which will really slow down the program.

Comment: As a side note, standard practice when writing any form of function-like macro is to put parenthesis around the whole expression.

Comment: @mattieu: yes, he wants to use `endl`: in debug its ok to slow down the program. And: you want to see each line on the console, as the program executes it. Not flushing would mean: you don't *see* what you just printed, sometimes. That hinders debugging.

Comment: @mattieu (and towi): Usually stderr is always unbuffered, so its already "flushing"(even if you dont specify it explicit) - just for the reason towi explained (debugging).

Comment: Are you considering any specific compiler or it must work "ansi-c" like?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [GNU C Language Extensions](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuexts.html) :

```
#define DEBUG(x)                                                 \
  ({                                                             \
    if (__builtin_types_compatible_p (typeof (x), int))          \
        fprintf(stderr,"%d\n",x);                                \
    else if (__builtin_types_compatible_p (typeof (x), char))    \
        fprintf(stderr,"%c\n",x);                                \
    else if (__builtin_types_compatible_p (typeof (x), char[]))  \
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",x);                                \
    else                                                         \
        fprintf(stderr,"unknown type\n");                        \

  })
```

These are fine:

```
DEBUG("hello"); //prints hello
DEBUG(11110);   //prints 11110
```

But for chars, you should use it with lvalue, otherwise its type will be "int" :

```
char c='A';
DEBUG(c);    // prints A
DEBUG('A');  // prints 65
```

Comment: You'll want to add `fflush(stderr);` to the end of the macro to get the same effect as `endl`

Comment: stderr isn't buffered actually, so the fflush is unneeded. And stdout is line-buffered, so the \n would take care of it in that case.

Comment: In the final else, how about `write`ing `sizeof(x)` bytes from `&x` to give at least a flying chance at getting useful data back?

Comment: The link for GNU C Language Extensions should be http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuexts.html

Comment: I added the missing 'l' at the end of the link. Thanks.

Comment: @Bruno  stdout is *not* always line buffered.  If stdout is a tty, then it will be line buffered by default, but stdout is not always a tty.

Answer (score 14):

You can't use `fprintf()` in the way you want. Welcome to C.

C++ I/O stream operators are typesafe and use operator overloading to achieve their magic. That's not available in C so you have to stick to unsafe format string approaches.

Answer (score 9):

In principle, you can't, as C don't have an overloading mechanism.

You can, however, define a number of macros like:

```
#define DEBUG_INT(x)  fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", (x))
#define DEBUG_CHAR(x) fprintf(stderr, "%c\n", (x))
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to get rid of the conversion specifications, but if you have a C99 compiler, you can use `__VA_ARGS__` and make it a little easier, as, for example, in

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUG(fmt, ...) fprintf(stderr, (fmt), __VA_ARGS__)

int main(void) {
  int foo = 42;
  char *t = "foobar";
  DEBUG("%s:%d\n", t, foo);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or easier yet: call the bloody fprintf() directly from the program  :)

Comment: @Konstantin: do you a reference for that `_Generic` keyword?

Comment: sorry, it's not C99, it's from new standard draft.

Comment: @Konstantin: I see '6.5.1.1' in [N1548.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf). Thank you :)

Comment: @Lundin, the point to have this in a macro is that it can be ignored in release builds.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you cannot reliably determine the type of an object. Hence, you'd have to introduce some mechanism to support generic programming, e.g. enclosing all objects in a structure which holds type information:

```
enum {type_int, type_double, type_string, /* ... */ } type_t;
struct {
        type_t type;
        void *obj;
} generic_type;
```

Now, you can switch over `((generic_type)my_object).type`. This is probably not what you're looking for.

However, there's a simple trick to tell whether a macro argument is a string literal or something else. With the macro quoting character '#', you can turn a macro argument into a string:

```
#define DEBUG(x) if (#x[0] == '"') printf("%s\n", x); else printf("%d\n", x)
```

Now you can do the following:

```
DEBUG("foo bar");  // prints "foo bar"
DEBUG(23);         // prints "23"
```

On the downside, this won't let you distinguish between e.g.`int`s and `float`s. Furthermore, pointers-to-char are not recognized as strings:

```
char *foo = "bar";
DEBUG(foo);        // prints the value of foo, not the string pointed to by foo

double salary;
DEBUG(salary);     // prints (int)salary, not (double)salary
```

On some machines, `sizeof(double) != sizeof(int)`. This might help to further distinguish between the different types of your macro arguments, but it's certainly not portable.

Generally speaking, you won't be able to completely solve this problem without some serious effort towards generic programming support while also maintaining portability.

My advice: simply get used to format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `__VA_ARGS__`, you can just simply do the following:

```
#define DEBUG(x...) fprintf(stderr, x)
```

Unlike the GCC built-in methods, this method allows you to mix-and-match - you can print "string=", instead of just one type at a time. You also won't run into size and type incompatibility this way - it's essentially the same as fprintf, except able to be excluded at build-time!